# how to remove this error : undefined method `inc' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**I wrote in your browser  " http://localhost:3000/items/create?name=car1&description=good+car&price=500000&weight=0&real=1 " , and I got an error**

**undefined method `inc' for nil:NilClass**

**Extracted source (around line #11):**

```
9 after_initialize { puts 'initialize' } 
10 after_save { puts 'saved' } 
11 after_create { category.inc(:items_count, 1) }  
12 after_update { puts 'updated' } 
13 after_destroy { category.inc(:items_count, -1) } 
14
```

**Rails.root: E:/work/my_store**

**Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace**

```
app/models/item.rb:11:in `block in <class:Item>'
app/controllers/items_controller.rb:9:in `create'
```

**Request**

**Parameters:**

```
{"name"=>"car1",
 "description"=>"good car",
 "price"=>"500000",
 "weight"=>"0",
 "real"=>"1"}
```

Comment: this is litterally telling you that you are calling the method `inc` on a `nil` object. In your code, you use `category.inc(some_args)`, then `category` is therefore equal to `nil`. Use `self.inc` instead, `self` referencing to the context you are executing the code, or use `after_create { |category| category.inc(:items_count, 1) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 11 you're doing `category.inc(:items_count, 1)` So it means that category is nil at the moment. I don't see a controller code, so my guess is that you either did not create category yet, or did not set `category` variable to a proper value. And actually there is usually no need to do things like

```
   category.inc(:items_count, 1)
```

because if everything is set up properly, you can always do

```
   category.items.count
```

to count all items in category.

Did you try to complete any tutorial yet? I recommend [Michael Hartl's tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/). It's simple, but you can learn quite complicated things from it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just learning and questions you may seem confusing, but thank you for understanding. I understand where the error